# Prawn gem: How to create the .pdf from an *existing* file (.xls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rubygems, prawn

Can anybody show me (maybe copy/paste a simple code example) how to create the .pdf file from an *existing* (.xls) file, using the Prawn gem? (Basically, I'd need the command that "opens" the existing file.)

(I'm asking because the Prawn documentation (http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/) seems to be gone since quite a while - it's not even usable via Google cache...)

Thanks a lot for any help with this!
Tom

Comment: Please edit to use `Prawn` instead of `Pawn` in title as well as text body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you break the problem down.

1. Can you read xls with Ruby? [Possibly](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ruby+read+xls&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but it's flaky at best.  However, you can [easily read csv](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/), and xls exports nicely to that format.
2. Can you write a 'table' of values to a prawn pdf?  [Yes](http://github.com/sandal/prawn/tree/stable/examples/table/)

So, (almost) all you need is a little program that can parse a csv file into a prawn-friendly table-structure and then hand it off to Prawn for generation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Prawn gem cannot handle existing files...

Comment: it can use existing PDF files as a template, but not files of arbitrary types.

Answer (score 0):

Prawn can be used to render content on top of a PDF.  You're talking about .xls, a completely different format.

Comment: Was this removed from Prawn? I'm trying to render on top of an existing PDF and I cannot find documentation anywhere on this.