# Ruby on Rails: Plugins/gems for converting a .xls file to a .pdf file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-plugins, spreadsheet

what are the Rails plugin/gem solutions for converting a .xls file into a .pdf file?

Thanks a lot for any feedback!

Tom

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prawn gem: How to create the .pdf from an *existing* file (.xls)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148370/prawn-gem-how-to-create-the-pdf-from-an-existing-file-xls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything that will do it without shelling out some cash.  You might be able to roll your own by combining the [roo gem](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) with the nice swanky [pdfkit gem](http://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit).  The roo gem would allow you to read the contents of the excel file.  You would then need to construct an html document and pass that to pdfkit which converts html to pdf.  That is a little indirect, but should get the job done.